# Pass control's ClientID to web user control property

Tags: asp.net, properties, webusercontrol

I need to get the label control's ClientID into web user control. Below is the property created in the Web User control:

```
 public string ExternalLabelToSetTheValue
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return labelToSetTheValue.Value;
            }
            catch { }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                labelToSetTheValue.Value = value;
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

and I want to pass the label's ClientID into this property. Below is the inline code but not working:

```
<cs:Slider ID="MaleChidCountSlider" runat="server" SliderID="MaleChidCountSlider" DisplayMode="simple" StyleUISlider="ui-sliderSimpleGraybox" StyleUIWidget="ui-widgetSimpleGraybox"
StyleUICornerAll="ui-corner-allSimpleGraybox" StyleUIState="ui-stateSimpleGraybox" ExternalLabelToSetTheValue="<%= lblChildrenCount.ClientID %>"/>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Ah, the famous "empty catch" design pattern. Always worked for me like a charm. Instant error-free applications!

Comment: did you tried `"<%# lblChildrenCount.ClientID %>" ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
<cs:Slider ID="MaleChidCountSlider" runat="server" 
           SliderID="MaleChidCountSlider" DisplayMode="simple" 
           StyleUISlider="ui-sliderSimpleGraybox" StyleUIWidget="ui-widgetSimpleGraybox"
           StyleUICornerAll="ui-corner-allSimpleGraybox" StyleUIState="ui-stateSimpleGraybox" 
           ExternalLabelToSetTheValue="<%# lblChildrenCount.ClientID %>"/>
```

or you can still set propery value in `code-behind`.

Comment: Call DataBind method on usercontrol to enforce data-binding evaluations. Did you try setting property value in code-behind also?

Comment: Yes.  public string MaleChildCountLabelClientID
        {
            get
            {
                return lblChildrenCount.ClientID;
            }
        } and ExternalLabelMaxValue='<%= MaleChildCountLabelClientID %>'

Comment: And, what about this: ExternalLabelToSetTheValue="<%# lblChildrenCount.ClientID %>" ?

Comment: It is taking as it is "<%# lblChildrenCount.ClientID %>" as a string.